# Usage of "self" in Python leetcode problem

Tags: python

I was working on 109. Convert Sorted List to Binary Search Tree on leetcode, and I came across a solution that I mostly understand, aside from the use of self.

The solution:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedListToBST(self, head):
        length = 0
        curr = head
        while curr:
            curr = curr.next
            length += 1

        self.head = head

        def recursion(start, end):
            if start > end: return None
            middle = (start + end) // 2
            # left
            left = recursion(start, middle - 1)

            # root
            root = TreeNode(self.head.val)
            self.head = self.head.next
            root.left = left

            # right
            root.right = recursion(middle + 1, end)
            return root

        return recursion(0, length - 1)
```

I get confused on the use of `self.head = head`. I understand `self` is used to indicate or specify the current instance of a class, and is used to access variables of said class. My current understanding of how this is working is that `self.head` is being defined as a global variable (outside the scope of `recursion(start,end)`) that points to the object `head`. I don't understand *why* self needs to be used, and *why* we can't just say something like `copyOfHead = head` instead of `self.copyOfHead = head`. I'm sure I'm getting some things wrong here - can somebody help me better understand the *what* and *why* of using `self.` in this instance?

Comment: The `recursion` function is referencing the same `self` that its parent method declares as a parameter, i.e. it's an up-level reference.  It refers to the class instance that was used to call `sortedListToBST`.  It's not global.

Comment: but I think you're right that in this case, referencing self is not providing any benefit here, unless solution.head is referenced outside this function.

Comment: The only reason to use `self.head` over `some_other_head` is if the value is accessed from another method, or if the user of the object somehow needs access to the value of `self.head` as `some_object.head`. If neither is the case, you're right, there's no point. Another possibility is that the author wasn't aware of `nonlocal` and decided on abusing `self.` as the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's just providing a global variable so that `recursion` (which will be called many times) can use it to store state between calls.

Leetcode is designed so that you have to use the class wrapper, but for this algorithm you could have easily written:

```py
self_head = None

def sortedListToBST(head):
    length = 0
    curr = head
    while curr:
        curr = curr.next
        length += 1

    self_head = head

    return recursion(0, length - 1)

def recursion(start, end):
    if start > end: return None
    middle = (start + end) // 2
    # left
    left = recursion(start, middle - 1)

    # root
    root = TreeNode(self_head.val)
    self_head = self_head.next
    root.left = left

    # right
    root.right = recursion(middle + 1, end)
    return root

# Run the function
sortedListToBST(some_input)
```

Which I think makes it clear that the object-oriented stuff doesn't matter, it's more about being a global variable. However, in your example, `recursion` is inside `sortedListToBST`, so I think it could have actually accessed `head` already. So I think using `self` was unnecessary and the author didn't realize it. In functional programming terms `self.head` allows `recursion` to have side-effects.

You could also eliminate the need for this global variable by just passing `head` in the arguments of `recursion`.